# Is it possible to vectorize this calculation in numpy?

Tags: vectorization

Can the following expression of `numpy` arrays be vectorized for speed-up?

```
k_lin1x = [2*k_lin[i]*k_lin[i+1]/(k_lin[i]+k_lin[i+1]) for i in range(len(k_lin)-1)]
```

Is it possible to vectorize this calculation in numpy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x1 = k_lin
x2 = k_lin
s = len(k_lin)-1

np.roll(x2, -1) #do this do bring the column one position right

result1 = x2[:s]+x1[:s] #your divider. You add everything but the last element
result2 = x2[:s]*x1[:s] #your upper part

# in one line
result = 2*x2[:s]*x1[:s] / (x2[:s]+x1[:s])
```

You last column wont be added or taken into the calculations and you can do this by simply using np.roll to shift the columns. x2[0] = x1[1], x2[1] = x1[2].

This is barely a demo of how you should approach google numpy roll. Also instead of using s on x2 you can simply drop the last column since it's useless for the calculations.